# Algorithm of constructing the graph for a partial order set

Tags: co.combinatorics, lattice-theory, boolean-algebras

Given a finite partial order set $(P,\leq)$. Is there an algorithm for constructing its graph, where, from bottom to top, the ordering goes up? Namely, I want to construct the directed graph representing the partial order set.

Any reference (books or papers) would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The vertices are the points of the set and the edges are comparables $a < b$ with no elements inbetween.  So you iterate over the set $P$, find all comparables for a given element, then the minimal ones are the edges.

Comment: @Ryan Budney That makes perfect sense. Thanks

Comment: If you are searching for algorithms: google "DAG topological sorting"